# How to add a number and a frame after textview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to add a framed number (@+id/number_ayat) right after the end of the text(@+id/isi_ayat), but it can't if I use textview. So how can I add numbers and frames after the end of the text?

This is my code in custom_isi_ayat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/number_ayat"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/frame"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:id="@+id/isi_ayat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/translate_bahasa"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/terjemahan"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

in capture result :[in capture result :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGHAz.png)

---

and I want to result is : [and I want to result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w6k2.jpg)

Whether this can be solved with java?

Thanks in advance for help with my problem !

Answer (score 0):

I have modeled the layout in Android Studio. I had to force rtl on my layout so there may be some things to correct. The first that I sugest is changing the width of `"@+id/isi_ayat"` as explained below.

The changes I did were the following:

In the LinearLayout I set `gravity` to `end` for the textviews to go to the right.

For `android:id="@+id/isi_ayat"`, I set `gravity` and `textAlignment` to `end` so the text aligns to the end of the TextView, and also set `layout_gravity` to `end` and `center_vertical` for the TextView to also go to the end. And also changed the `width` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="end">

            <TextView
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/number_ayat"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:text="10"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:id="@+id/isi_ayat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                tools:text="lorem ipsum dolo asd"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT I**

I removed `android:layout_marginRight="10dp"` from `android:id="@+id/number_ayat"`.

As you can see in the picture below. There is no more space between the two textviews.

This is the closest you can get without making the number's textview smaller.

[image]

**EDIT II**

I think I understood, if there are more lines the number must be after the last line.

Change `android:gravity="end"` to android:gravity="end|bottom" in

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="end">
```

Comment: Sorry start mmarginStart argin only change the position of number_ayatonly, not put number_ayatto end of text

Comment: I edited the answer completly. Take a look when you can.

Comment: Sorry I just have time to reply, I have tried and the result is fixed, the number is not exactly at the end of the text, he is just to the left of the text element, can this be solved with java? @Juan

Comment: Check your layout in Android Studio Designer. If you add the tools namespace as I did at the top of your layout and tools:text in the textview you can see how it looks with dummy data. If you turn on the blue print you can have an idea of how spaces is being taken. The only thing I see affecting space is this: android:layout_marginRight="10dp" Is it the same if you remove that?

Comment: Simple thinking, the sentence is quite a lot, I really want the number is right after the text, sorry if my term is hard to understand

Comment: See EDIT I in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updatenya but try give more text, number is not right after text :(

Comment: I think I understood, check EDIT II.